# du reports directory size as much bigger than the sum of its contents

Tags: shell, wildcards, disk-usage

Running `du -shc *` in the top directory gives `110G` for a particular folder, whereas running the same command inside that folder gives a total size of `11G`. How is that possible?

Platform Details:
OS: CentOS 6.6 x86_64
Drive type: solid-state
Volume type: RAID 6 array
RAID Controller: LSI MegaRAID SAS
Filesystem: ext3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most probably you have hidden files in the folder.
The point is that glob `*` selects only files and folders that do not start with `.`. So, if they do they are not passed to `du` command. On the other hand from top directory you get size of the directory as a whole, including dot files.

To match all files in given folder, including hidden ones try (with `bash`)

```
du -shc -- {.[!.],..?,}*
```

or set option `dotglob` so that `*` matches hidden files too:

```
shopt -s dotglob
du -shc -- *
```

Comment: Boy, am I embarrassed. I didn't think of that. I wish there were a simpler shell syntax for including hidden files in the expansion. Especially with commands like du, where you usually want to see everything in the folder. Thanks.

Comment: @orodbhen This glob is a little bit nerdy to take care of any "unusual" possibilities like files which start from two dots `..abc` or which start from hyphen `-abc`. Most of the times you could just do `du -shc * .??*` or  in shorter form `du -shc {.??,}*`. You cannot get rid of `?` to not take parent directory `..` into account. You can also set `dotglob` option in bash, so that it includes hidden files by default (I will add that to the answer).

Comment: @orodbhen In zsh: `*(D)` (or make the inclusion of dot files the default with `setopt glob_dots`).

Comment: Been using Linux command line for 12 years, never even heard of the shopt command!